# JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory error using GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am getting below error even though I had set the correct path for gecko driver.

Main:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class firstCase {
    @Test
    static void titleControl(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Program Exe's\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");          // Wee need that as Intellij doesn't know where it looks for browser
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(),"Google");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
1594880236960   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\yasin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofiledXH35Y"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
1594880239039   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 49419
1594880239073   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Tem 16, 2020 9:17:19 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the question? I'm not sure what your error is. In my case, the same shows up in the console but it works just fine

Comment: Actually my test is passed too but when I see `JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.` I suspect about what is wrong. Does it a problem?

Comment: Yea this happens if JS is not enabled on your browser. Check [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Turn-On-Javascript-in-Mozilla-Firefox#:~:text=From%20the%20Tools%20menu%2C%20click,or%20Preferences%20(on%20Mac).&text=Click%20the%20Content%20tab.,your%20Firefox%20browser%20can%20display.&text=Click%20Enable%20JavaScript%20or%20Enable%20Java%20.) out.

Comment: hmm, interesting I follow the instructions but mine is already enabled.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506768/how-to-capture-javascript-errors-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message...

```
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
```

...implies that there was a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) error while [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) initiated/spawned a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox* browsing session.

---

When [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven *GeckoDriver* initiates a *Firefox* browsing session there can be a couple of *JavaScript* related *`WARNINGS`* and *`ERRORS`* as a part of *`TRACE`* level logs during initialization. You can safely ignore those initialization errors till *GeckoDriver* is successfully able to initiate a *Firefox Browsing* session.

---

### Conclusion

When the `createSession` is successful and **`W3C`** dialect is detected you can safely ignore the errors.

Comment: Hmm, So I search about that. So, the errors are not important right? If the test passed.

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB, I was waiting for upvote and accept for finding true answer.